# What's the best terminology for switching from a mobile site to the "full" website?

Tags: mobile, usability, terminology

I've seen links to switch to the "Classic" site or the "Standard" site and I was just wondering if anyone did any testing with this. I like the sound of "full" but I have nothing to back it up. Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: I've also heard it called the "desktop" version but that's not quite right either.

Comment: The best solution is to not have a mobile site. Just have a single site and use responsive design techniques to make it render as needed based on the device/resolution.

Comment: Charles: This is how I would have done it, but it's out of my hands.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have no researched data to give you, but two personal observations:

1) Flicker uses flickr.com as the link back to the main site. This makes sense in the context that their mobile site is m.flickr.com.

2) I really like IMDB's method:

View IMDb in: Mobile | Desktop

with the one you are not currently looking at being made a link. The advantage of this option is the context is clear that there are two versions of the site.

Comment: I definitely approve of method 2, and I've seen it quite a lot. The first option only makes sense if A) Your user noticed they're on m.flickr.com and B) They know the convention that m.domain means a mobile site and that removing the m will return them to desktop mode.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using **View Full Website** with no problems on various projects. I prefer this wording because it marks the potential differences in functionality and content between mobile and desktop views, but doesn't assert the differences along the lines of device choice.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it would be the best if your site is able to detect the visitors screen resolution, and switch to a version which is designed for his/her own device. (tablet or mobile as well)

And in this case I would display the opprotunity to **"View Desktop Version"**.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably call it the "standard site view", as the only thing which is changing is the type of view of the website you're seeing. You're not changing a version - as it's essentially the same content and the way it works